# Multistep Nested Forms Using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wizard, nested-forms, multi-step

I'm trying to implement a multistep form using a nested form, but since I'm using a nested form, it's not working out like the railscast. I got this from railscast #217 (multistep form/wizards) http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms

#### old _event.html.erb form

```
<%= render "event_details", :f => f %>

<%= render "sandwich_details", :f => f %>
```

#### new version of _event.html.erb

```
<%= render "#{@event.current_step}_details", :f => f %>
```

I get a "undefined method `current_step` for nil:NilClass" error. 
I think this is because `event` is nested inside `user`, so I'm not directly 
using a forms_for method like in the railscast. Here's the loop leading up to 
this point. I followed the railscast up to the point where he refreshed the page 
for the first time.

#### _forms.html.erb

```
<% form_for @user do |f| %> 
.
.
.
   <% f.fields_for :events do |event_form| %>
      <%= render :partial => 'event', :locals => {:f => event_form } %>
   <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

#### event.rb

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_writer :current_step

  def current_step
    @current_step || steps.first
  end

  def steps
    %w[event_details item_details]
  end
```

How can I change `"#{@event.current_step}_details"` to make it find current_step?

### EDIT

It turns out I had to pass `@event => :event` into the locals, and then add `@event = Event.new` to the base model `new` method in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @reti notinh wrong with your methode but just a little chage you need is

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_writer :current_step

  def current_step
    @current_step || steps.first
  end

  def steps
    %w[event item]
  end
```

And rest is same as you did earlier, thums up.